Usage of 思い上がり in this sentence

俺に何ができるのかずっと考えてる。。。


別にそれでよくないっすか? 何かできるとか思ってんなら思い上がりっすよ

In the first bubble the character explain that "I've been thinking all this time what I can do"
Then the character answer that to him. But I don't quite get his answer? "If you think you can do something you are being presumptuous"? Maybe I'm reading 別にそれでよくない wrong here? Isn't it akin to "Isn't that good"?

それでよくないですか is です-form of それでよくない (with rising tone), so as you understand it means isn't that good?. You may be missing the difference それはいい and それでいい. In this case, it's で, implying good enough, (at least) satisfactory, (just) fine. So a more faithful translation may be it is fine, just like that / there's nothing wrong with it.
You can look at:

いいじゃない vs よくない, whats the difference?
What does そんなところでいい mean here?
What is the difference between それでいい and それがいい here?

For the second sentence, literally "If you think you can do something you are being presumptuous" should be perfect. The speaker is suggesting doing something more is none of the first speaker's business.
